# Control the ARM Cortex M3/M4 DMA rate to peripherals.

Tags: arm, gpio, cortex-m, dma

I want to stream data, byte-by-byte, from RAM to a port (GPIO pins) on an ARM Cortex M3 (and possibly M4 in future).

Is there a way of controlling the rate, relative to the bus speed?

i.e. if I'm running the M3 at 100MHz, can I do DMA at 10MHz, for example?

Comment: Cortex-M3 is just a CPU core - without knowing what actual MCU that M3 is a part of, nobody knows what DMA controller hardware you have, thus what that is capable of. Also, are you talking about the _writes to the GPIO controller_ happening at 10MHz, or the _data on the external pins changing_ at 10MHz? The former seems a bit odd, and there's one obvious ghetto solution for the latter - just write each word 10 times. For that, whether you have to duplicate the data manually or the DMA controller can do it for you brings me back to the first point.

Comment: @Notlikethat: A DMA transfer takes a lot more than one clock cycle and the exact timing is not deterministic in a useful way.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way of controlling the rate, relative to the bus speed?

Use a timer to trigger the DMA transfer.

> if I'm running the M3 at 100MHz, can I do DMA at 10MHz, for example?

Depends on the microcontrollers implementation of GPIO, DMA and timer. Those are usually *not* ARM provided peripherials - vendors implement them in different ways.

Comment: I'm looking to control the rate of the DMA transfer.  Please correct me, but wouldn't using a timer to trigger the DMA transfer would only control when it started?  (Unless I use multiple 1-byte DMA transfers controlled by a timer - or is that your point?)

Comment: Depending on your MCU, the DMA may support post-incrementation of the memory or peripheral pointer, so that after each transaction the pointer is increased by one. So each time the Timer triggers the DMA it would transfer one byte/half-word/word to the GPIO, and then increment the source memory pointer by one. You may configure it to stop after a certain number of bytes, or to wrap around in circular buffer mode. Like Turbo J said it all depends on what your particular Cortex-M3 MCU supports.

Comment: @chisdew You should either elaborate on your exact microcontroller to get a more detailed answer or accept this one.